# Typescript nested array mistyping issue

Tags: typescript

I need to pass *data* with the structure shown below

```js
export const Legend = ({ data }: { data: [string, number][] }) => ....
```

Why Typescript types *test* array in the way like in picture `(string | number)[][]`, instead of `[string, number][]`

[image]

Of course, I can overwrite the type, but I do not think this is a good approach

Comment: If your question is really "why does Typescript do this?", the answer is because if it inferred `[string, number]` instead of `(string | number)[]` for an array containing a string and a number, a lot more people would be annoyed about it. Consider using a different type like `{s: string, n: number}`, or just write the type annotation.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is your side issue. `[string, number][]` is an array whose elements are `string` and `number` pair. I assume you'd like to type `test` more specific than `(string | number)[][]` (NOTE: If so, it is called [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which you should avoid).

You may want to use [const-assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), which can be done by prefix expression by `as const`, like this:

```
const test = [
    ['C2B', 'D2C', 'PDP', 1],
    ['C2B', 'D2C', 'PDP', 2],
    ['C2B', 'D2C', 'PDP', 4],
    ['C2B', 'D2C', 'PDP', 2],
] as const;
```

You should change `Legend` signatures, too:

```
export const Legend = ({ data }: { data: readonly (readonly [string, string, string, number])[] }) => ...
```

The `test` elements are typed an specific type which is subtype of `readonly [string, string, string, number]`. The outer `readonly` modifier means entire array is read-only and you cannot change its contents. This is side effect of const-assertion, which does not have opt-out way.